# MessageBird: How to read a response from consumer

Tags: python-3.x, sms, sms-gateway, messagebird

I am evaluating MessageBird service. I got a Virtual Mobile Number. I am able to send message to dummy numbers (until i get approval for sending messages to real USA number)

**Unknown**: My problem is about reading the messages received by a VMN.

**Details**: If I as a VMN owner send a message to consumer e.g. +1(111)111-1111 and i am interested in reading the response from the consumer, how to do get it?

MessageBird documentation expects me to know the ID for response message object (or my understanding is wrong). The documentation is good but i don't see a way to programmatically achieve it. Any suggestions How to achieve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Messagebird have a feature of forward incoming sms data through webhook(get or post method). if you set an url then Messagebird will forward every incoming sms to you(or your server). You can easily read get/post response.